# In return to libc how do you know the address of system() in a remote machine?

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow

I have the following scienarion:

a vulnerable program running in a server and can be accessed using netcat

I have a copy of that program locally and I can exploit it locally using ROP:

```
./vuln garbage + &system() + &exit() + &"/bin/sh"
```

now I want to exploit it remotely so technically I would be executing this command:

```
echo -e "garbage + &system() + &exit() + &/bin/sh" | nc host port
```

My problem is: I do not know what is &system() on the remote machine. Is there any way to get it without brute force ie: trying all memory address from 0x00000000 -> 0xFFFFFFFF

*ps: &exit() is negligible but good-to-have*

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskNetsec/comments/25gl05/finding_ret2libcs_system_address_on_a_remote/chh0m39) reddit post. The following ways can be followed to obtain system() address on a remote machine for later return 2 libc exploitation.

1. **No ASLR:**
   Find out their version of libc/msvcrt. It should (Windows makes no guarantees, Linux shared libraries don't either) be loaded at the same address every time. Find address of system, use it.
2. **Partial-ASLR (no PIE):**
   The original binary will be loaded in the same place every time (again no guarantees on Windows). Find entry of libc/msvcrt function in the GOT/IAT, use that address.
3. **Full-ASLR:**
   You need an information leak.